# How to find the number of matrices of a given type using combinatorics?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

How can I find the number of matrices of the type \begin{bmatrix}a&a+1\\1-a&-a\end{bmatrix} where $a \in [-24,24]$. 
 I was solving an abstract algebra problem which turned into combinatorics at which I am not good. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: The mapping from $a$ to the matrix is bijective. Therefore the number of matrices is equal to the number of different values of $a$. If your $a$ is an integer, there are $49$ of them. If it can be any real number inside $[-24,24]$, the answer is infinite.

Comment: Surprized that you need help for such an elementary issue ; but may be you have forgotten a supplementary hypothesis ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I was asked to find the number of involutory matrices of lenght 2 over ${Z_2}_6$. Then I found that a matrix of the type given in the question is involutory. Now I must calculate the number of such matrices.

Comment: Here is the supplementary assumption : $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{26}= \{0,1,...25\}$ (mod. $26$). Therefore, the answer is $26$.

Comment: No need to consider "negative values" because in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$, $-1=25,-2=24$, (mod $26$) etc...But why do you exclude $25$ in your question ?

Comment: Because the second element is $a+1$ which is $25$ for $a=24$.

Comment: If $a=25$ then the top right entry would be $25+1$ which is perfectly valid and would equal zero.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, it is valid but then the matrix in not involutory.

Comment: It is involutory. You may need to revise number theory as well.

Comment: This wouldn't be motivated by an exercise in cryptography by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the comments reveal that this is an X-Y problem, I'll go straight to the real problem.

Goal: count the matrices $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$ such that $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ over $\mathbb{Z}/26\mathbb{Z}$.

We get four equations: $$\begin{eqnarray}
a^2 + bc &\equiv& 1 \\
ab + bd &\equiv& 0 \\
ac + cd &\equiv& 0 \\
bc + d^2 &\equiv& 1 \end{eqnarray}$$

So $a^2 \equiv d^2$ and $d \equiv \pm a$. We can case split:

#### Case 1: $d \equiv -a$

Then the second and third equations tell us nothing about $b$ and $c$, so we're just left with $bc \equiv 1 - a^2$.

We have one value of $a$ which gives $bc \equiv 1$, one value of $a$ which gives $bc \equiv 14$, and two values of $a$ for each product $bc \in \{ 0, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 18, 23, 24 \}$. These can be further split according to their GCD with $26$.

- $bc \in \{ 1, 5, 11, 15, 17, 23 \}$: both must be units, so there are $\varphi(26)$ solutions per value of $a$, for a subtotal of $12 \times 11 = 132$ solutions.
- $bc \in \{ 0 \}$: one or both is divisible by $2$, and one or both is divisible by $13$. There are $51$ solutions per $a$ where one or both of $\{b, c\}$ is zero; and $12 \times 1 \times 2$ where one is even non-zero and the other is $13$, for a subtotal of $(51 + 24) \times 2 = 150$ solutions.
- $bc \in \{ 2, 4, 10, 14, 18, 24 \}$: the values of $\{2,4,6,\ldots,24\} \times \{2,4,6,\ldots,24\} \bmod 26$ are evenly distributed among the twelve non-zero even residues, and similarly $\{1,3,5,\ldots,25\} \times \{2,4,6,\ldots,24\} \bmod 26$ are evenly distributed among the thirteen even residues (including zero), giving a subtotal of $(12 + 12 \times 2) \times 11 = 396$ solutions.
- $bc \in \{ 13 \}$: one of $\{b, c\}$ must be $13$ and the other must be odd, giving a subtotal of $25\times 2 = 50$ solutions.

#### Case 2: $d \not\equiv -a$

If $d \equiv a$ then the middle equations give us $2ab \equiv 2cd \equiv 0$, so either $13 \mid a$ (in which case we're in case 1) or $13 \mid b \wedge 13 \mid c$. In the latter subcase, there are three pairs $(b, c)$ with product $0 \pmod {26}$ and one pair with product $13 \pmod{26}$. If the product is $0$ then $a^2 \equiv 1$, with two solutions (neither of which is divisible by $13$); if the product is $13$ then $a^2 \equiv 14$, with two solutions (neither of which is divisible by $13$). Thus we have eight solutions in case 2.

Totalling everything up, we have $132 + 150 + 396 + 50 + 8 = 736$ solutions.

Comment: NB After thinking about it for a while, perhaps the intended approach is to show that if $f(n)$ counts the $2 \times 2$ involutory matrices over $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ then $f$ is a multiplicative function. $f(2)$ is so simple that it can be done by inspection, and $f(p) = p^2 + p + 2$ for $p$ an odd prime.